# How to format a table of data in Emacs using elisp?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I want to format a table of data automatically in Emacs using elisp with the awesome `table-insert` command. My idea is to do something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
(defun make-table ()
  (interactive)
  (table-insert 2 1) ; Table with 2 columns and 1 row
  (insert "first cell contents")
  (table-forward-cell)
  (insert "second cell contents")
  (table-release)
  )
```

Instead of inserting the "first cell contents" in the table, it inserts the text just before the first cell, so the text doesn't go into the table at all. Then it crashes on the `(table-forward-cell)` call.

When I do this interactively, it works fine--how is the elisp code above different from doing it manually with my keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Reason is that the insert "destroys" the table, as it moves the `|` character.  Then `(table-forward-cell)` fails because it cannot "parse" the table in the buffer.

My advice would be to take a look to `org-mode` and the table relate functionality it provides.  Then, you will figure out which one suits your needs better, `table` or `org-mode`

Comment: How can I make it not destroy the table? When I do `M-x insert-table` manually, a table is created and the point automatically gets put into the first cell, so subsequent typing goes into the cell (plus the modeline says `Table`). I'll consider org-mode but I'd really like to understand what's different between elisp and interactive editing here.

Comment: When you do it interactively... does the insert moves the `|` chars t the right?  Do you use "overwrite mode"?  That may be the difference.  `insert` function does not insert text in a cell, inserts text in the buffer, and so "destroys" the table

Comment: No, it doesn't move the `|` chars over when you it interactively--it works correctly. (I meant `M-x table-insert` btw.) I don't think `insert` overwrites anything and I don't think the buffer and the cell are different things -- the cell is just a special region of the buffer. I guess the real question is, how can you exactly mimic interactive typing using elisp?